# How to sign a message using private key of the certificate in javascript

Tags: javascript, cryptography, digital-signature, pki

I have a CNG/CAPi certificate on my local drive. It is imported in the windows certificate store.I want to access it from the Browser like(Chrome,IE etc.). How can i sign the message/nonce(provided by server) using private key of the certificate in windows certificate store with Javascript/Jquery/Any Browser API?  Is there any api i can refer? Or pls let me know the process by which i can sign the message using javascript? I have tried WebCrypto Api ,but no success. I need to build it from scratch so any help would be appreciated. The code is below :

```
     var client = forge.tls.createConnection({
        server: false,
        caStore: { HOST: 'CN=ret512312.abc.xyz.net, O=xyz, S=ZG, C=CH' },
        cipherSuites: [
            forge.tls.CipherSuites.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            forge.tls.CipherSuites.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        ],
        verify: function(connection, verified, depth, certs) {
            debugger;
            if (depth === 0) {
                var cn = certs[0].subject.getField('CN').value;
                if (cn !== 'example.com') {
                    verified = {
                        alert: forge.tls.Alert.Description.bad_certificate,
                        message: 'Certificate common name does not match hostname.'
                    };
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the main criticisms about the WebCrypto API is that it provides no access to the trust points in the cert store of the browser. Of course it also doesn't provide access to trust points for the entire system either (that would be bad). So you have to break out of the sandbox of the browser to perform this feat.

Breaking out of the sandbox could be done through e.g. browser extensions, but please note that these are kind of on the way out, as not every (mobile) browser supports them, and you'd have to program them for each browser separately. Previously you'd have signed applets to do this, but those have been depricated long ago (after complete mismanagement by Sun / Oracle if you ask me).

So yeah, no, sorry. It's probably better to setup a trusted website and then recover a signed certificate from there, if it is really required (but note that you would not be able to gain much more security than that provided by the initial TLS connection).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can we do so using browser extension/browser plugins? Pls guid on that part as well.

Comment: My requirement is basically on the top of the TLS , as server  needs to authenticate a machine(client,subject here is machine).So, certificate validation is the only way to do so.